# How to handle SD card/no SD card scenario in PhoneGap File API?

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry

I am using the PhoneGap File API in a BlackBerry app. I have the following line of code:

```
fileSystem.root.getFile("myfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileReaderEntry, readfail);
```

In the BlackBerry simulator, this line of code does not work when there is no SD card present and the process of accessing/creating the file ends. I don't even get a fail callback. When I mount an SD card on the simulator, it works perfectly.

How do I get this working in devices that have no SD card?

Answer (score 0):

haven't used PhoneGap before, but why not put it in a simple try/catch block?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand how to code a proper try/catch block, but nothing is "caught".try {
     fileSystem.root.getFile("myfile.txt", { create: true }, gotFileReaderEntry, readfail);
    } catch(e) {
     alert(e);
    }

Comment: Is readfail a function or variable? What's the value of the "readfail" after the function is called....it looks like it's the last thing passed.

Comment: readfail is a function. In the Phonegap docs the readfail function does the following: console.log(evt.target.error.code) ... However, in this case, nothing is logged to the console. If I replace the console.log line with alert('readfail'); I do get the failure alert. If I try to do alert('readfail:'+evt.target.error.code); I get no alert!

Comment: So then if your alert('readfail') was working....maybe there's a way you can get out of it. Could you declare a global variable, and then set the value of that variable inside the fail callback that was successfully doing your alert('failure')?

Comment: I was able to get the console log working. The only information it returns is "Error Code 1".

Comment: lame. best of luck! have you seen this yet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13664102/phonegap-cordova-blackberry-filesystem-root-always-returns-sd-card

Comment: Yeah, I saw that earlier, though the code used in the accepted answer is virtually identical to mine so I don't see why mine won't work. :(